# Javascript library html2canvas: error message when rendering

Tags: javascript, html2canvas

Using html2canvas (js) try to convert an html element to png, but I get an error message when rendering.
Use this code:

```
    html = $('#mySpan img')[0];
    html2canvas(htmlSource, {  
                onrendered: function(canvas)  
                {
                    var data_png = canvas.toDataURL("image/png")                
...
    }).then(
            // error callback
            function(error){
                    console.log(error);
    });
```

It only indicates in error:

```
<canvas width="600" height="136" style="width: 600px; height: 136px;"></canvas>
```

When opening the url like "data:image/svg+xml;base64, ...." in the browser, get this error:

***This page contains the following errors:
error on line 1 at column 173: AttValue: ' expected
Below is a rendering of the page up to the first error.***

To understand better, how the console showed the rendering and the error:

[image: consola]

With which tool can see what is the problem with the syntax? Any ideas how to debug the problem?
Thanks

Comment: `.then()` is usually not the error callback, its `.catch()`

Comment: @Ifaruki With catch you do not enter the callback.

Comment: `.then()` captures the response, `.catch()` captures the error